# Compare ACF on two post types to create a query

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I need to compare ACF from two post types to create a query.

I have a CPT called 'issues' and have a datepicker on this page.
I am using the default post type for my other post type and I also have a datepicker on this page.

I would like to create a query on the *issues-single.php* page that will pull in default posts if the dates match up on both post types.

For example: If the datepicker on my issues-single page is January 2017 I would like to query all my defualt posts that also have that same date selected in the datepicker

Here is the code I have so far but I just turn up with a "page not working" error.

```
<?php
$current_page_year = get_field('issue_date');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_per_page' => '1',
    'meta_key' => 'article_date',
    'meta_value' => "$current_page_year",
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($my_query->have_posts())
{
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="small-12 medium-8 columns" id="mag-feature">
            <p class="mag-cat"><?php the_category(', ') ?></p>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('quorum-featured'); ?></a>
            <div class="mag-news-content clearfix">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <a class="mag-read-more" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read More</a>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>
        </div><!-- end #mag-feature -->
```

Comment: Try removing " from here: "$current_page_year" - should be simply $current_page_year. Are you sure it's stored in DB in form of 2017 for example and not 2017-01-11, etc.?

Comment: Removing the " still gives the same result just an error page and to be honest im not sure how its pulling the date in. To be honest I just need to compare the month and year the date does not matter to me.